# Do not send "SPAM FROM LOCAL" messages for mails relayed to spam_lovers

Tags: spam, amavis

I have setup amavis as follows:

```
$policy_bank{'ORIGINATING'} = {  # mail originating from our users
  originating => 1, # indicates our client, introduced in amavisd-new-2.5.0
  ...
  spam_admin_maps  => ["spamalert\@$mydomain"],  # warn of spam from us
};


@spam_lovers_maps = ([ qw( abuse@ spam.spamcop.net )]);
```

I have added spamcop to spam_lovers, because I send/forward spam there myself,
and Amavis was blocking it before.

Now, I've got an "SPAM FROM LOCAL" warning to the spam_admin address, after having sent a bunch of spam to the spamcop submit address (using my gmail account as a sender, not the local domain - but sent through my smtp).

I do not want to get the warnings when spam is sent from LOCAL to any spam lovers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@spam_admin_map uses also a hash lookup table and lookup is done with a per-recipient key.

Therefore you can replace the spam_admin_maps line in the policy bank with something like this:

```
...
spam_admin_maps => [ {"abuse\@spam.spamcop.net" => undef},  "spamalert\@example.com" ],
...
```

Examples can be found in the file amavisd.conf-sample which is delivered with amavis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am currently using the following as a workaround: `@bypass_spam_checks_maps = ([ qw( spam.spamcop.net ) ]);` and `@bypass_virus_checks_maps = ([ qw( spam.spamcop.net ) ]);`